# Simulate multiple camera sources

Tags: javascript, web-applications, camera, agora.io

How can I simulate a user having multiple camera sources (e.g. more than 1 webcam), without having to have more than one webcam on my machine? This is for manual testing purposes for a web application.

Note: I am using a macbook as my machine

Thank you!

Comment: You can open the same webpage on multiple tabs or maybe you are requirement is more related to creating multiple instance of RTCEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Install virtual camera on your macbook machine. Just search 'virtual camera on mac' and you will find the way to install it on mac.
This link may be helpful https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam/releases

For windows machine **"droid cam"** is an easy way to install virtual camera and mic.

Answer (score -1):

Like the comments suggested, You can simply open the application on multiple tabs to simulate new users.